# Set intero as default in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

How do I set `intero-mode` as default for my Haskell buffers instead of `haskell-mode`?

Answer (score 3):

I looked it up and `intero-mode` is a *minor* mode, not a major mode.  You probably want to be using that *with* `haskell-mode`, not *instead of* `haskell-mode`.

The library also contains a globalized minor mode which knows what to do, so you could just add the following to your init file:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'haskell-mode
  (require 'intero)
  (intero-global-mode 1))
```

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `intero-mode-maybe` <kbd>RET</kbd> which is used by the globalized mode to decide whether or not to enable `intero-mode` in any given buffer.

---

FYI if `intero-mode` had been a major mode, then the answer to your stated question would have been:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hs\\'" . intero-mode))
```

but in this case you don't actually want to do that.